# Request Entity Too Large

Tags: configuration, web-hosting, php

I get this message,

```
Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource
/index.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

I set

```
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
```

in `.htaccess` but not helped

How to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: fwiw, i had the same error. it was because i was using a POST request, but not passing any fields. content-length is probably zero which probably signifies infinite.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After you are over the raising of PHP's [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize), I would like to recommend you some articles related to the topic, maybe one of them solves the problem.

I found this post on Server Fault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/79741/php-apache-post-limit/79745#79745

- **sybreon** suggests to double-check the `Content-Length`, and - citing - *"ensure that you are directly connecting to Apache and not through either a proxy or a reverse-proxy. Some reverse-proxies place a cap on the maximum size of a request as a sort of security measure. So, you may want to check that as well as your Apache logs to ensure that nothing else is going on."*
- sybreon also posted this link: [Apache 413 error problems](http://blog.bombcar.com/2008/01/apache-413-error-problems.html).
  The following is only applicable **if you have [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient) module turned on** in Apache. (Otherwise this setting can cause a server crash.)
  Citing the article:
  *"I was using Apache SSL client certificates, which have a limit of 128K, and if re-negotiation has to happen, a larger POST will fail.

  [This Bugzilla posting](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12355) had the clues - You have to set the following as DEFAULTS for your SSL server, not just the directory.*

  ```
  SSLVerifyClient require
  ```

  *Otherwise it forces a renegotiation of some sort, and fails with a 413 error."*
- The previous article also mentioned the [**LimitRequestBody**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive.
  [A guy says here that the appropriate setting of this directive solved his problem.](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2302244&sid=a654b905c1d75eb03aff1773a00c77ad#p2302244).

I hope one of these settings solves this problem!

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that would work for me was to tune up the SSL Buffer Size. You can set this by...

```
<Directory /my/blah/blah>
...
  # Set this to something big...
  SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
...
</Directory>
```

...and then just restart Apache for the change to take effect. (Found this at: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2085574)

You can also use "Location /" to simply apply the setting to a whole VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# ...
    <Location />
        SSLRenegBufferSize 101048600
    </Location>
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Note that this needs to be set on the receiving end. So not on the proxy. On the **destination** Apache httpd.

Answer (score 10):

My server is Apache. It was mod_security module which was preventing post of large data approximately 171 KB.
I did below configurations in mod_security.conf

```
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 10486000
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 10486000
```

Comment: This was the one for me too!!

Answer (score 1):

If max_post_upload and max_file_upload in PHP has been set,
and there is a setting in Apache2.conf or ModSec config files of LimitRequestBody set high enough

then possibly a .htaccess file will work.

1. Go to the directory with the upload php file in it ( the file or page throwing the error.)

2 . Make or edit .htaccess

3 . Edit or create a line with 
    LimitRequestBody 20971520   in it.

4. Save the .htaccess. Set permissions. ( 644  and apache owner)
5. Possibly restart apache.

Tada . Hopefully fixed.

This setting sets that limit for this folder only - which is one way to avoid a global setting in php and apache which makes you open to large packet / load DOS attacks.

LimitRequestBody 0   gives you unlimited uploads.

Answer (score 1):

After raising of PHP's memory_limit, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini, I still had the problem.

What was also needed was the following in apache2.conf:

LimitRequestBody 1000000000

That's for a max size of 1GB.

The docs say that 0 is the default, which means unlimited.  However, until I set the directive, I couldn't upload large files.

Don't forget to restart apache2.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this 413 - Request entity too large problem for last day or so, as I was trying to upload farely large (in MBs) images to the server.

My setup is apache (227) proxying requests to jboss eap (6.4.20) server for accessing rest endpoints.

2 Things worked for me.

1. Make SSLVerifyClient required at the virtual host level. This means all the resources need a valid client cert presented to be served. This was not an option for me as all the resources except /api should NOT be mutual auth protected. So, while it worked, this was not an option for me.
2. I removed the global level SSLVerifyClient required and kept it 'optional'. I re enabled required option only on `<Location /api>...</Location>`. Trick was to have the SSL renegotiation happen only after a certain threshold is reached - which would be our desired upload file size.
3. So, finally it turned out that I had to enable 'SSLRenegBufferSize' setting on a specific LocationMatch as follows:

   `<LocationMatch ^/api/v1/path/(.*)/to/(.*)/resource/endpoint$>

   SSLRenegBufferSize 5242880 #allow upto 5MB for files to come through 
   </LocationMatch>`

(.*) in the case above represents my path params in the endpoint. Hope this helps.