# 413: Request entity too large apache php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have been getting this 413 response when trying to upload an ~20MB zip file with a home grown (but not by me) document library resource developed in PHP running on an Apache server with a MySQL database connected.  Normally the max file size is limited to 5.2MB in a local PHP variable.  So the first thing I did was to increase this value and try to upload the file. That's the first time I encountered this error.

I tried everything mentioned here: [Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896644/request-entity-too-large)

And even changed the `mod_security` config settings mentioned in the bottom of that post.  Even with all the limits I found raised far above what I should need -- up to ~120MB, I still get this error.

Comment: try to incrase `max_post_size` also.

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me maybe this helps you to upload larger files:
Change these values in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize 3000M
post_max_size 3000M
max_execution_time 3600
max_input_time 3600
```

Comment: I looked in php.ini and the limits there were already larger than I needed.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

So after posting this, I found another mod_security limit that needed to be raised appropriately.

SecRequestBodyLimit was too low (131072).

This is probably a corner case, but hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I found this setting for apache in `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf` on my ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

Do you increase `LimitRequestBody` in your apache config? [Link to LimitRequestBody in Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Comment: Yes i tried that, since it wasn't already set, and it defaults to 0 (infinite), I don't think this made much difference.  Thanks for your response anyway!

Answer (score 0):

None of the listed fixed my problem. They were all set much higher than needed.  I was posting 100k-500k textarea fields.  What did fix it for me was adding the following to the <form> tag.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```