# STILL 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, html, apache, post, http-status-code-413

Running apache2.2 with php5.
Trying to upload a 1.9MB image file and is getting `Error 413 Request Entity Too Large`. Tried all the possible settings I could find so far and is still giving me that error, can anyone think of anything else that I am missing?

- SSLRenegBufferSize 2147483647
- SSLVerifyClient require
- LimitRequestBody 2147483647
- post_max_size = 1536M
- upload_max_filesize = 1536M
- phpinfo() shows the configured values

Disregard those **huge** numbers, what/where else am i **STILL** missing? ugh

Comment: How are you trying to upload this file?

Comment: Via https POST, weird thing is, same setup works for another instance, I carried over the configs (ones mentioned above) and not sure what else I am missing...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896644/request-entity-too-large