# cURL SSL error with large file

Tags: php, ssl, curl, http2, fpm

I'm trying to make some backup of my production server and send the backup compressed in tar.gz in another server. This was working fine before updating my server to php7.2-fpm (for HTTP2.0).

I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

Here is the configuration of my two servers:

**- Production server :**
- System : Linux debian2 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64
- Apache : Apache/2.4.33
- Php : PHP Version 7.2.5-1 (with FPM api)

**- Backup server :**
- System : Linux debian2 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3 (2017-12-13) x86_64 
- Apache : Apache/2.4.10
- Php : PHP Version 7.1.13-1 (with Apache 2.0 handler)

The backup server is still with HTTP1, the production server use HTTP2 protocol.

So in order to make my backup, i go to my root folder and just compress everything inside as a .tar.gz.

To send the file here is the code i use :

```
/**
 * @brief Sends a file.
 * @param      Array          $data    The data to send (backup file path, file name)
 * @param      String|string  $action  The action (platformBackup, databaseBackup)
 * @return     Array|boolean
 */
public static function sendFile(Array $data, String $action) : Array
{
    $cFile = curl_file_create($data['file']);
    $data['save'] = $cFile;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,SERVER_SAVE_URL.'/'.SERVER_SAVE_TOKEN.'/' . $action . '/'.PLATEFORM_ID);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === false)
    {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return $result;
}
```

This works with a small file (less than 1Gb). But not with larger one.

My first thought was a bad configuration of Apache and php7.2-fpm because everything worked great before.

But i think that this is ok, here is the variables i changed in my php/7.2/fpm/php.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 10800 
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 10000M
upload_max_filesize = 10000M
```

I also try to force them in the php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf but nothing change.

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT :**

I update my backup server to Apache 2.4.33 and enable HTTP2.0 protocol with php7.2-fpm. When i try to backup i got a message in my error log :

```
[Tue Jun 12 13:10:34.829260 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9092:tid 140388941666048] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)
```

From a php7.1-fpm server i got

```
503 Service Unavailable
```

From a php7.2-fpm i got :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SSL read:error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

Since nothing worked with php and apache I told myself that the problem came from elsewhere, i watch my filesystem which is ext4 so no problem with large file and i try to send a backup with SCP which work great too. So for me the problem only come from PHP, Apache or cURL.

As a reminder, the backup works for a little server (800mb) but not for larger one (3.4Gb)

**EDIT 1 :**

It seems that SSL is the problem, when i disable it on my backup server everything works. As a temporary solution i just encrypt the file with openssl with a generated key and send it to my backup server.

Comment: When you dump your configuration with `phpinfo()`, do you see the same parameters ?

Comment: This is not an SSL error  (SSL error is 0) but the peer has closed the connection (errno 104 is connection reset by peer). Thus, don't look at the SSL level for problems. Look at the target servers error log for possible details on what might have caused the server to close the connection.

Comment: @Flyzzx I just cheked the phpinfo() of the two servers and everything is corrrect and correspond to what i want.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I just the the apache error log, nothing happen in the file when i'm trying to backup the server. No error. Is there another apache logs then the one i configure in my virtual host ?

Comment: @HugoPierrat: I have no idea about your config but I think that the log messages should be in the error log you have configured (not access log). If you configured the error log at the VirtualHost or a global error log is unknown to me.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich There is nothing in the apache error log i've configured in my virtual host, i tried to backup a server in php7.1-fpm version and this time the error is not the same i got a "503 Service temporary unavailable" I'm will investigate today and try to give you some news. don't hesitate to post if you have any idea ! Thanks !

Comment: You may have max_execution_time shutting down the sending script when file takes long to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** in these other topics:

- [Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896644/request-entity-too-large)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/709646/apache-2-2-ssl-large-file-upload-fail

It is explained how to raise the SSL buffer size at apache config (which could be your problem).

```
<Directory /my/site/here>
...
  # Set this to something big...
  SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
...
</Directory>
```

Source: @kongekrabben

**

I have seen many of these problems in our corporate apps, mainly because the web servers were old to support new cipher suites.

In order to completly discard SSL I would run the following test using openssl:

To Test TLS1.2

```
openssl s_client -connect ${DoMain}:${port} -tls1_2
```

Change `-tls1_2` to `tls1` or `tls1_1` or `ssl3` to test other cipher suites.

The above will simulate a SSL handshake and transmission, if all good it should end with exit code 0.

To read the exit code at bash, just `echo $?` after executing the previous command

Then, a nmap scan will list all SSL ciphers available from a server, please note this is an invasive test and could actually trigger Security Software resulting in banned requester’s IP. DO NOT use this second test unless you are sure what you are doing:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers ${DoMain}
```

Hope this helps.

Then, depending on the results set this in your PHP libcurl declaration:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, $int);
```

Where `$int` stands for the SSL cipher suite to be used:

- CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0)
- CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1)
- CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2)
- CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3)
- CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4)
- CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5)
- CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6)

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

**@stackOverflow admins:** I am sorry, I wanted to comment but do not have enough points to do so. Please edit or copy/paste then remove my answer and place it in a comment if needed.

Comment: related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896644/request-entity-too-large

Comment: I don't understand why this can change anything, i can send a 800mb file without any problem, and by default `SSLRenegBufferSize` is set to 128MB. I try every SSL version on my cURL request and nothing change. for the moment i can't try your solution, but i keep it in my mind and when i will have some time, i will try it and tell you ! Thanks for your help !